# Passing multiple method arguments as a loop or a string

Tags: swift, function, coreml

I have a coreML model with an input method of more than 50 arguments. Writing them one by one would be super tedious, but I can't figure out how to do it programmatically, i.e. by a string or a loop.

```
let model = myModel()
let modelInput = myModelInput(//here all the arguments: arg1 : Int, arg2 : Int, arg3 : Int, arg4 : Int, etc.)
guard let myModelOutput = myModel.prediction(input: modelInput) else {}
```

I can write with a loop all the arguments, in a string or a dictionary, but myModelInput won't accept it. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: As @matt said you can use the Dictionary method, but if you have 50 arguments that are all the same type, it might make more sense to stick them into a vector (i.e. an MLMultiArray) and just pass that into the model.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have control over the model input class/struct? If so, give it another initializer, a convenience initializer that calls the real one. Now you *can* pass a dictionary or whatever you have decided upon. And the dictionary can be constructed programmatically.

Thus the tedious part still exists but it is moved away from the call sites and into the class itself, where it needs to be written just once.

Comment: Well, it works, though I had imagined another way to do so, but my basic problem - the many arguments hard-coding - remains. Is there another way to pass a label? I mean, like in a for loop: for x in 0...50 {arg[x]=myvalue}

Comment: That is a dictionary. I don’t see what else is needed here.